# snap.svg element addeventListener load event loop not working

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I am in the middle of creating an animated icon for everyday use. Selecting one element by id works fine, but using multiple elements in one code doesn't work. How can I make multiple elements work?

the link is my code.
url : https://codepen.io/choimorae/project/editor/XVyLdV `enter code here`

--> The first document icon can be animated well, but the second document icon cannot be animated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop through the list of elements with the class name of `.ico_snap_doc_obj`. That looks fine, but when you assign `$wrap` and `$doc_obj` it seams like it is just the first element with the class name `.ico-doc-wrap` you select (and in the second case it should be the second element).

```
        let $doc_obj = document.querySelectorAll(".ico_snap_doc_obj");
        let doc_obj_length = $doc_obj.length;
        for(var i=0; i<doc_obj_length; i++){
            $doc_obj[i].addEventListener("load", function(){
                let $wrap = Snap.select(".ico-doc-wrap");
                $doc_obj = Snap.select(".ico_snap_doc_obj");
```

Try to solve this by selecting the elemenst based on their id (like `id="ico_snap_doc_wrap"`) and then give the elements a unique id (like `id="ico_snap_doc_wrap_2"`).

```
        let $doc_obj = document.querySelectorAll(".ico_snap_doc_obj");
        let doc_obj_length = $doc_obj.length;
        for(var i=0; i<doc_obj_length; i++){
            $doc_obj[i].addEventListener("load", function(){
                let $wrap = Snap.select("#ico-doc-wrap_" + i);
                $doc_obj = Snap.select("#ico_snap_doc_obj_" + i);
```

So, here you would have two elements, one with the id `ico-doc-wrap_0` and one with the id `ico-doc-wrap_1`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Thanks to this, I learned what was wrong with my code and I was able to fix it safely.